# Spark JDBC Read, Partition On, Column Type to Select?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying a read a SQL Table (15 million rows) using Spark into Dataframe, I want to leverage Multi-Core to Do the read very Fast and do the Partition, What are the column/s I can select to partition ? is it ID, UUID, Sequence, date-time? How should I calculate the Number of Partitions?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple of complex questions in your question : 
- What are the column/s I can select to partition ? 
It depends on your needs and your computing goals and transformations that you will do next with spark on your data. (if groupBy(key) and your key is date-time, then you should partitionBy date-time)
- Number of partition depends on : the size of your data, your hardware ressources, yours needs ... it is a complex question, you have to take into account shuffle partitions for transformations also (default is 200, value advised by spark: 3 * number of cpu)

```
  val sparkSession = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder
    .master("local[*]")
    .appName("JdbcMicroService")
    .getOrCreate()
  sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 3 * nb CPU)

  def requestPostgreSql(sparkSession: SparkSession, database : database, dateOfRequest : String) : DataFrame = {

    val url = "jdbc:postgresql://" + database.url + "/" + database.databaseName

    val requestDF = sparkSession.read.format("jdbc")
      .option("Driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
      .option("url", url)
      .option("dbtable",database.tableName)
      .option("user",database.user)
      .option("password",database.passwd)
      .load()
        .repartition(col("colName"))

    requestDF

  }
```

Comment: Sandeep540, Did i help you ?